# How to mock typeorm @Transaction attribute

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, typeorm, ts-jest

I need to write a unit test for a method of my service, and everything was working fine till I decorated the method with `@Transaction`,

```
@Transaction()
    async inbound(lead: Lead, @TransactionManager() entityManager?: EntityManager) {
```

after which I started to get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined

      at src/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.ts:845:25
      at PostgresDriver.Object.<anonymous>.PostgresDriver.obtainMasterConnection (src/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.ts:844:16)
      at PostgresQueryRunner.Object.<anonymous>.PostgresQueryRunner.connect (src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:98:58)
      at PostgresQueryRunner.<anonymous> (src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:204:47)
```

if I remove the Transaction attribute all works as needed.

I tried to use `sinon` to mock the attribute

```
stub(typeorm, 'getConnection').returns(connection);
stub(typeorm, 'Transaction').returns(jest.fn());
```

but it doesn't help.

tried to also mock just that attribute

```
beforeAll(() => {
            jest.mock("typeorm", () => ({
                ...jest.requireActual("typeorm"),
                Transaction: jest.fn().mockImplementation(jest.fn())
            }))
```

but still no luck.

Is there any other way to mock it?

thx

Comment: well, it turns out this works ok with typeorm: 0.2.30, with the latest typeorm version 0.2.35 it won't, guess something internally was changed